# Delete files within my download folder

Tags: files

I may have too many dang random files in my download folder because every time I try to get into it my explorer crashes after loading for a bit and I have to reboot my whole pc. I just wondered if there was a way to clear what was in the folder WITHOUT having to delete the whole folder itself. The main reason I don't want to delete the whole folder is because I don't know if that would cause some sort of error in Ubuntu so I figured I'd see if I could clear it first. Also I used ClamTk to check for viruses in that folder and found none.

Comment: Did you tried the command line?

Comment: Which command do I use? I honestly want to just clear everything in that folder and although I'm better at Linux than I was, I'm still nowhere near savvy enough to know what to do now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deleting the Downloads directory shouldn't cause any errors.

Use the following commands to remove and recreate it:

```
rm -r /home/username/Downloads
mkdir /home/username/Downloads
```

Replace username as applicable, or you may use the shortcut `~` (tilde key, at the top left of your keyboard) to replace `/home/username`, like so:

```
rm -r ~/Downloads
mkdir ~/Downloads
```

The [Ubuntu Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#File_.26_Directory_Commands) has a good overview of the terminal commands, if you're curious to learn more about them.

Comment: OKAY THANK YOU SO MUCH! I'm gonna use search to move out the files I need and then just delete everything else! You were so much help just now!

Comment: youre welcome. and continue to enjoy using ubuntu

Comment: I already do, been using it for almost a year now and it's become my fave after switching from *Excalibur reaction face* Vista.....